# Javascript variables and memory leaking?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory-management, memory-leaks

Is it possible to create memory leaks when coding in Javascript? and if so is this dependent on the Javascript rendering engine e.g. V8 or IE's Chakra

I seem to be getting really slow performance when iterating through large loop constructs.

Should i "delete" the variables that im not using?

```
var myVar = 'very very long string';
delete myVar;
```

Comment: No, the vm will take care of that, please post the code that is giving you issues

Comment: That's not how `delete` works. Sure memory leaks are possible. I have no idea what that has to do with your slow performing loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you've shown, unless `myVar` is in the global scope it will simply be garbage collected at the end of the function.

In general, you don't need to worry about memory in JavaScript. Where you do need to worry about memory is when you unintentionally create references to objects and forget about them. For example:

```
function buttonClick() {
    var clicked = false;
    document.body.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        if (clicked) return;
        if (event.target.nodeName !== 'button') return;
        clicked = foo();
    }, true);
}
```

The above code is **bad code** to begin with (not cleaning up event listeners), but it illustrates the example of a "memory leak" in JavaScript. When `buttonClick()` is called, it binds a function to the `click` event on the `<body>`. Because `removeEventListener` is never called to unbind the listener, the memory used by the function is never reclaimed. That means that every time `buttonClick()` is called, a little bit of memory will "leak".

Even then, however, the amount of memory leaked is quite small and won't ever become a problem for the vast majority of use cases. Where it would likely be a problem is in server-side JavaScript, where the code is potentially run much more frequently and the process stays alive for much longer.